# Capturing Photo from PhotocaptureDevice

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8, image-capture

i my creating an image editing application. i want to give the option to user that he can also capture the image at run time and apply editing effects on that captured. at the moment i am following the instructions from [Advanced Photo Capture for windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

there are 2 problems
First that i am facing is that when i hit the capture button the image captured will be an inverted image. if i put the phone in Landscape mode then it take the right picture.

When the app starts there is nothing on the screen in other words its totally black. I want the screen to show the camera view so that user knows that what he is going to capture.

Below is my code for Mainpage.xaml.cs file and MainPage.xaml file.

```
namespace CapturingPhoto {
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage {

    private MemoryStream imageStream;
    private PhotoCaptureDevice captureDevice;
    private CameraCaptureSequence seq;
   // Constructor
    public MainPage() {
        InitializeComponent();
        imageStream = new MemoryStream();
        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();

        prepareResouceToCapture();
    }

    private async void prepareResouceToCapture() { 
        if((!PhotoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Back)) &&
            (!PhotoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Front))){
                return;
        }
       Windows.Foundation.Size size;
        if(PhotoCaptureDevice.AvailableSensorLocations.Contains(CameraSensorLocation.Back)){
            IReadOnlyList <Windows.Foundation.Size> avalaibleSizeList =  
                PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Back);
            size = avalaibleSizeList[0];
            this.captureDevice = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Back, size);
        }
        else{

            IReadOnlyList<Windows.Foundation.Size> avalaibleSizeList =
                PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Front);
            size = avalaibleSizeList[0];
            this.captureDevice = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Front, size);

        }


     //  await this.captureDevice.SetCaptureResolutionAsync(size);
      // await this.captureDevice.SetPreviewResolutionAsync(size);
     //  BackgroundVideoBrush.SetSource(this.captureDevice);




    }



    private async void onCaptureImage(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        seq = captureDevice.CreateCaptureSequence(1);
        captureDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraPhotoProperties.FlashMode, FlashState.On);
        captureDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.PlayShutterSoundOnCapture, false);
        captureDevice.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.AutoFocusRange, AutoFocusRange.Normal);
        seq.Frames[0].CaptureStream = imageStream.AsOutputStream();
        await captureDevice.PrepareCaptureSequenceAsync(seq);
        CaptureImage();


    }


    public async void CaptureImage() {
        await seq.StartCaptureAsync();

        // Set the stream position to the beginning.
        imageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
        Picture picture1 = library.SavePictureToCameraRoll("image1", imageStream);

    }


}
```

}

Code for Xaml file

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="CapturingPhoto.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="768" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- LOCALIZATION NOTE:
        To localize the displayed strings copy their values to appropriately named
        keys in the app's neutral language resource file (AppResources.resx) then
        replace the hard-coded text value between the attributes' quotation marks
        with the binding clause whose path points to that string name.

        For example:

            Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"

        This binding points to the template's string resource named "ApplicationTitle".

        Adding supported languages in the Project Properties tab will create a
        new resx file per language that can carry the translated values of your
        UI strings. The binding in these examples will cause the value of the
        attributes to be drawn from the .resx file that matches the
        CurrentUICulture of the app at run time.
     -->



    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->

    <Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.ZIndex="0">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Canvas.Background>
            <!-- The background contains the camera view finder
                 encapsulated in VideoBrush. -->
            <VideoBrush x:Name="BackgroundVideoBrush" >
                <VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="VideoBrushTransform" CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                </VideoBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </VideoBrush>
        </Canvas.Background>
    </Canvas>

    <Button x:Name="btn_Edit" Content="Capture" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="23,691,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="400" Click="onCaptureImage"/>



    <!--Uncomment to see an alignment grid to help ensure your controls are
        aligned on common boundaries.  The image has a top margin of -32px to
        account for the System Tray. Set this to 0 (or remove the margin altogether)
        if the System Tray is hidden.

        Before shipping remove this XAML and the image itself.-->
    <!--<Image Source="/Assets/AlignmentGrid.png" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="800" Width="480" Margin="0,-32,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsHitTestVisible="False" />-->
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that string:

```
BackgroundVideoBrush.SetSource(this.captureDevice);
```

is comment.
You can't see camera view, if VideoBrush is empty.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question use the "EncodeWithOrientation" property. Put the following switch statement at the top of your onCaptureImage(). This will ensure the saved image is in the correct orientation when taking a photo in portrait mode.

```
     // Initialize variables.
        int encodedOrientation = 0;
        int sensorOrientation = (Int32)this._camera.SensorRotationInDegrees;

        switch (this.Orientation)
        {
            // Camera hardware shutter button up.
            case PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                encodedOrientation = -90 + sensorOrientation;
                break;
            // Camera hardware shutter button down.
            case PageOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                encodedOrientation = 90 + sensorOrientation;
                break;
            // Camera hardware shutter button right.
            case PageOrientation.PortraitUp:
                encodedOrientation = 0 + sensorOrientation;
                break;
            // Camera hardware shutter button left.
            case PageOrientation.PortraitDown:
                encodedOrientation = 180 + sensorOrientation;
                break;
        }
        // Apply orientation to image encoding.
        this._camera.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.EncodeWithOrientation, encodedOrientation);
```

Also see the following on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.knowncamerageneralproperties.encodewithorientation(v=vs.105).aspx